# Finding longest running queries from within functions and procedures

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a procedure execution query and this procedure in turn calls functions which in turn may/may not call other functions. All these procedures and functions have multiple queries with in. 
I want to check which were the longest running queries in this process.

I found this script online but this does not work for me. It returns only the create procedure/function statements which may have taken longest times but it is not returning anything beyond that and probably not looking inside functions and procedures as I selected TOP 1000 rows and yet it returns somewhere around 60-70 rows which are only create statements and nothing else .

Can I please get some help on this? Thank you

```
  SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10000
    t.TEXT QueryName,
    s.execution_count AS ExecutionCount,
    s.max_elapsed_time AS MaxElapsedTime,
    ISNULL(s.total_elapsed_time / s.execution_count, 0) AS AvgElapsedTime,
    s.creation_time AS LogCreatedOn,
    ISNULL(s.execution_count / DATEDIFF(s, s.creation_time, GETDATE()), 0) AS FrequencyPerSec
    FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats s
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text( s.sql_handle ) t where t.dbid = DB_ID() 
    ORDER BY
    s.max_elapsed_time asc
    GO
```

Comment: You need to look at the offsets to find the statement within the object. Don't re-invent the wheel and write this stuff yourself; look at [Glenn Berry's scripts](https://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/category/diagnostic-queries/), for example.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Thank you so much for your response But I was not able to find it in those scripts.

Comment: Did you search the script for the word "offset"? Maybe look for this: `Lists the top statements by average input/output usage for the current database  (Query 39) (Top IO Statements)` and you can just change the ORDER BY...

Comment: @AaronBertrand: That was so beautiful :) Thank you so much :) :)The query worked like a charm.